# Python Jinja2 loop index to make id unique

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm using jinja2 template with Flask and MongoDB and I need to display users' cars in a template.

I was able to render cars in the `profile` template with car information and buttons to edit or delete a car. The problem is that if a user has multiple cars, only the first *DELETE CAR* button actually works (where I have an include modals to confirm) but nothing happens when click on the second or third *delete* button. Apparently I duplicated the `id` that needs to be unique. But I cannot achieve the results.

Here is my template: `profile.html`

```html
{% extends 'layout/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
{% include 'components/navigation/navigation.html' %}

<div class="container">
    <div class="row g-3 justify-content-center">

        <div class="col-6 mt-5">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h3 class="text-center profileHeader">
                        {{ username }}'s profile
                    </h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="row row justify-content-center mt-4">
        {% for car in cars %}


        {% if session.user|lower == car.created_by|lower %}


        <div class="card mb-3" style="max-width: 840px;">

            <div class="row g-0">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <img src="{{ car.car_image }}" class="imgCard" alt="ferrari image">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">

                            <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Year</strong>: {{ car.car_year }} </li>
                            <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Name</strong>: {{ car.car_name }}</li>
                            <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Designer</strong>: {{ car.car_design }}</li>

                        </ul>

                        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">


                            <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Engine</strong>: {{ car.spec_engine }}</li>
                            <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Power</strong>: {{ car.car_power }}</li>
                            <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Trasmission</strong>: {{ car.trasmission }}</li>

                            <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Races</strong>: {{ car.races }}</li>
                            <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Wins</strong>: {{ car.wins }}</li>
                            <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Podiums</strong>: {{ car.podiums }}</li>
                            <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Poles</strong>: {{ car.poles }}</li>
                            <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Fast Laps</strong>: {{ car.fast_laps }}</li>
                            <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Constructor Championship</strong>: {{
                                car.constructor_champ
                                }}</li>
                            <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Driver Championship</strong>: {{ car.drivers_champ }}
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Description</strong>: {{ car.description }}</li>

                            <p><em>by: {{ car.created_by }}</em></p>


                        </ul>

                        <div class="d-grid gap-2 d-md-flex justify-content-md-end">

                            <a id="myBtn" class="btn btn-danger"><i class=" fas fa-trash-alt"></i> Delete</a>

                            <a href="{{ url_for('editcar', car_id=car._id) }}" class="btn btn-danger" id="edit-btn"><i
                                    class="far fa-edit"></i> Edit</a>
                            {% with car_id=car._id %}
                            {% include 'components/modals/confirm.html' %}
                            {% endwith %}
                        </div>



                    </div>



                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

        {% endif %}

        {% endfor %}


    </div>
    enter code here

</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make unique the tag id of delete button, so the trigger will be unique in every button. How to make unique ? just add the `car._id` on tag id

```
<a id="myBtn-{{car._id}}" class="btn btn-danger"><i class=" fas fa-trash-alt"></i> Delete</a>
```

Comment: Thanks Darn for your input, is actually the same, I even try to use loop.index like so: <a id="myBtn-{{ loop.index }}" class="btn btn-danger"><i class=" fas fa-trash-alt"></i>

Comment: anyone know how to style this dynamic id.

Answer (score 0):

As @Darn pointed out, your `ids` need to be unique. But that is not the cause of your issue here.

I assume you have some Javascript code that gets triggered when user clicks on the delete link. The issue is probably from how that code is being triggered. The code needs to be written in such a way that it is bound to dynamically generated elements (you're generating the delete links on the fly i.e. afte the code for the delete was already bound; that delete code needs to also apply to each element when it is created).

You should bind the delete action to a class e.g.

```
$(".fa-trash-alt").on("click", function(){
    $(this).parent() ...... // this is the link to the instance of the link that was clicked

});
```